# Ransack - Grouping to use or combinator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ransack

I have some issues using the grouping functionalities of the Ransack gem.

I have a lot of conditions in my search form and I want to perform a OR between to of them such as :

WHERE condition_x = "xxxx"
AND condition_y = "yyyy"
AND (website_present OR eshop_present)

So so far what I did is building the grouping in my controller :

`@q.build_grouping({:m => 'or', :website_present => "", :eshop_present => ""})`

And then tried to display it in my form as follow :

```
- @q.groupings.each do |g|
  - g.conditions.each do |c|
    - c.conditions_fields do |x|
      - x.value_fields do |v|
        = v.check_box :attribute, checked: :value
```

And... nothing happen, no error and no display.

I also tried many many other way to display it but nothing worked and I can't find a proper example to do it. Even with the ransack demo, I was unable to figure a way to do it without adding a select_predicate and select_attribute fields.

Hope you will be able to help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Question is quite old and I don't know if it is still relevant, but I had this issue too today and will leave answer here if someone will need it.

It looks like you were not creating groupings correctly. Here is the code that helped me.

In you controller you need to build grouping:

```
     @q = SomeModel.search(params[:q])
     @q.build_grouping unless @q.groupings.any?
```

Then in your view:

```
   = search_form_for @q do |f|
     = f.label :field_a_eq, 'Field A'
     = f.text_field :field_a_eq, 'aaa'
     = f.grouping_fields do |g|
       = g.hidden_field :m, value: 'or'
       = g.label :field_b_eq, 'Field B'
       = g.text_field :field_b_eq, 'bbb'
       = g.label :field_c_gteq, 'Field C'
       = g.text_field :field_c_gteq, 'ccc'
```

As result you should get query like this:

```
   WHERE field_a = "aaa" AND (field_b = "bbb" OR field_c >= "ccc")
```