# Merging two active record associations rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filter, ruby-on-rails-5

We are implementing filters in ruby on rails and where the filters may combine with AND/OR conditions.

**To achieve OR between filter conditions**

Filter 1 OR Filter 1 OR Filter 3 = We achieved this with the rails or method(https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html) by combining two active record relations with OR.

For eg: the filter conditions are,

**`id is 1 or id is 2`**

To achieve this,

`Person.where(id: 1).or(Person.where(id: 2)`

The query produced will be,  `SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE ("people"."id" = $1 OR "people"."id" = $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]`

**To achieve AND between filter conditions**

The main problem we faced is to combine filters with AND condition,

**`id is 1 AND id is 2`**

We tried to use [merge method in rails](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) but with that method, the same conditions will be overridden by the most recent condition. Found this as well [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33501)

```
Person.where(id:1).merge(Person.where(id:2))
# The first condition is overridden by second, if the same condition is on the same column.
Person Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]
```

Note: the example I provided may look simple but the filter logic is really complex, so we can't just be chaining rails scopes there.

**`((id is 1 or id is 2) AND (id is 10 or id is 20))`**

This is how a simple filter will look like. There is much more complexity can be added. Our filter will look like [ransack demo app](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search).

What we will do is combine all inner blocks with OR and combine all outer blocks with AND. Can anyone suggest a better approach if the filter condition is AND and the column is to be queried in the same column?

Thanks in advance.

We also thought to get the where conditions and do string concatenation. But hope that is the worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve `OR` and `AND` between filter conditions, you can simply use [arel table](https://devhints.io/arel). Arel table make comlex query simpler and easier to do.

Another way, you can still use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). I think [this](https://medium.com/@jaspercurry/searching-and-sorting-on-rails-with-ransack-560e862e650a) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349699/ransack-grouping-to-use-or-combinator) is what you want in `ransack`.

Comment: We are filtering in JSON columns and we need to cast and make queries there. So we can't use ransack

Comment: I think I confuse with your issue. Does you want to filtering like https://datatables.net/manual/ajax, and filter tool like ransack demo app ?

Comment: Filter like ransack

Comment: If you want to filter like ransack, 2 posts: https://medium.com/@jaspercurry/searching-and-sorting-on-rails-with-ransack-560e862e650a , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349699/ransack-grouping-to-use-or-combinator are good references to make filter like ransack, even you are filtering in JSON columns. What is your really issue with ransack, can you make it clear ?